# match elements in two vectors within a range

Tags: r

I have this type of data in the following vectors.

```
v1 <- c(15, 20, 30, 45)
v2 <- c(17, 23, 30, 55)
```

I would like to match each element only if they fall within a certain range of the elements in `v1`. My code is:

```
ifelse(v1>v2-5, match(v1, v2), 0)
```

My intended output is: `[1] 1 2 3 0`

Instead, I get: `[1] NA NA 3 0`

Why are the first two elements not matching?

Answer (score 1):

The third value is the only element in `v1` that matches `v2`, hence you get `NA` for the other elements even though your condition is met.  `ifelse()` will insert the following values for elements that return a `TRUE` value the condition:

```
match(v1, v2)[v1 > v2 - 5]
# [1] NA NA  3
```

You may try using a sequence there instead:

```
ifelse(v1 > v2 - 5, seq_along(v1), 0)
# [1] 1 2 3 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for `findInterval`.

```
findInterval(v1, c(0, v2))
#[1] 1 2 4 4
```

The 3rd value of the result is wrong, so argument `left.open` must be set to `TRUE`.

```
findInterval(v1, c(0, v2), left.open = TRUE)
#[1] 1 2 3 4

ifelse(v1 > v2 - 5, findInterval(v1, c(0, v2), left.open = TRUE), 0)
#[1] 1 2 3 0
```

Comment: How, if the two vectors were different lengths, given the correct interval, could I make it so that lets say v1[2] would match with v2[3]?

Comment: @Raegan.H If the two vectors are of different lengths then so would be `v1` and `v2 - 5` and `ifelse(v1 > v2 - 5, ...etc...)` would issue a warning. This is also true for `match` and would change the problem completely.

Answer (score 0):

```
sapply(v1, function(x){
    temp = which(v2 >= x & abs(v2 - x) < 5)[1]
    replace(temp, is.na(temp), 0)
})
#[1] 1 2 3 0
```

Comment: I think it would be useful to add a bit of context to this answer. For example, why did the attempt of the OP not work?